# Allocating structure memory dynamically t times in loop instead of declaring array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, structure

`Original code (using array of structure):` In this code I am taking `t` as input from user and declaring a structure array `tc` of size `t` and then doing some processing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,i,j,k,min=0;
    //# of test cases
    scanf("%d",&t);

    struct testcase
    {
        int sizeOfArray;
        int a[10];
        int b[10];
        int ans;
    };

    struct testcase tc[t];            //declaring array of structures, size t 

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&tc[i].sizeOfArray);  //entering size of a and b
            for(j=0;j<tc[i].sizeOfArray;j++)   //entering elements of a
                    scanf("%d",&(tc[i].a[j]));

            for(j=0;j<tc[i].sizeOfArray;j++)   //entering elements of b
                    scanf("%d",&tc[i].b[j]);                    
        }
    int no=0;
    for(k=0;k<t;k++)
        {
            min=    tc[k].a[0]+tc[k].b[1];
            for(i=0;i<tc[k].sizeOfArray;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;(j<tc[k].sizeOfArray);j++)
                        {
                            if((tc[k].a[i]+tc[k].b[j]<min)&&(j!=i))                        
                                    min=tc[k].a[i]+tc[k].b[j];
                        }
                }
            tc[k].ans=min;
            printf("%d\n",min);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

`What I have tried:`
Here instead of declaring array of structure of size t, I am allocating structure memory dynamically in for loop and doing same processing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int t,i,j,k,min=0;
    //# of test cases
    scanf("%d",&t);
    struct testcase
    {
        int sizeOfArray;
        int a[10];
        int b[10];
        int ans;
  };

    struct testcase *tc = NULL;          

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            struct testcase* tc = malloc(20 * sizeof(*tc));
            scanf("%d",&tc[i].sizeOfArray);  //entering size of a and b
            for(j=0;j<tc[i].sizeOfArray;j++)   //entering elements of a
                    scanf("%d",&(tc[i].a[j]));

            for(j=0;j<tc[i].sizeOfArray;j++)   //entering elements of b
                    scanf("%d",&tc[i].b[j]);                   
        }
    int no=0;
    for(k=0;k<t;k++)
        {
            min=tc[k].a[0]+tc[k].b[1];
            for(i=0;i<tc[k].sizeOfArray;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;(j<tc[k].sizeOfArray);j++)
                        {
                            if((tc[k].a[i]+tc[k].b[j]<min)&&(j!=i))
                                    min=tc[k].a[i]+tc[k].b[j];
                        }
                }
            tc[k].ans=min;
            printf("%d\n",min);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

`Question:` Why second code is not working ? What corrections needs to be done, in second code, did I use `malloc` properly ?, Is `malloc` at right placed ? or any syntax error or logical error is there?

Comment: You're allocating a new array each time through the loop, and the `tc` variable is local to the loop body, so it can't be accessed in the next loop. Allocate it once before the loop.

Comment: Why do you think you need to allocate it dynamically in the first place? What was wrong with the original version?

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @Barmer , here  malloc should be there only once and also outside the loop, then it will work same as previous (like struct array tc[20]), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically allocate an array of `struct testcase`, so you only need to do it once, before you enter the loop.

```
struct testcase *tc = malloc( t * sizeof(struct testcase));
if (!tc) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}

for(i=0;i<t;i++)
...
```